# Why Parse.Query function is not work?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I use to Parse Cloud Code.
now I can not unsolvable problem.
It is this code.
This 1 code is not problem working ,but 2 code is not work.
Why?

```
    var className = Parse.Object.extend("Post");


    //--------------------------1 Start-----------------------------
    var post = new className();
    post.set("ArtistName","Name");
    post.set("Collection","アルバム");
    post.set("MusicTitle","タイトル");
    post.set("user",toUser);
    post.save(null, {
         success: function(gameScore) {
            console.log("クラス保存成功");
        }
    });
    //---------------------------1 end----------------------------

    //-------------------------2 start-----------------------------
    var query = new Parse.Query(className);
    //query.equalTo("user", toUser);
    query.count({
        success: function(count) {
            console.log("Sean has played " + count + " games");
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log("エラー");
        }
    });
    //--------------------------2 end-------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you provide is valid except one line. You have to call response success as below;

```
  var query = new Parse.Query(className);
//query.equalTo("user", toUser);
query.count({
    success: function(count) {
        console.log("Sean has played " + count + " games");
        response.success(count);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log("Error");
        response.error(error);
    }
});
```

After calling the success you can see the count both in the logs and function caller.
Hope this helps.

Regards.